# SSO connection within same salesforce org

Tags: single-sign-on

We have two communities - Partner Community and Customer community. we need a Partner community user to login into customer community. These two already exists in Production. 
A user can be part of both communities. so, they are creating separate User records with respective licenses. 
Now they need SSO, for a Partner user to login into customer community.
While implementing this facing an issue. 
Error '**Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user. Subject: 00DXXXXXXXXXXXX@p1@sf.com**'
I have mentioned Partner's username as Federation Id of Customer user's record.

Below is the SAML validator results :

Unexpected Exceptions
  Ok
1. Validating the Status
  Ok
2. Looking for an Authentication Statement
  Ok
3. Looking for a Conditions statement
  Ok
4. Checking that the timestamps in the assertion are valid
  Ok
5. Checking that the Attribute namespace matches, if provided
  Not Provided
6. Miscellaneous format confirmations
  Ok
7. Confirming Issuer matches
  Ok
8. Confirming a Subject Confirmation was provided and contains valid timestamps
  Ok
9. Checking that the Audience matches
  Ok
10. Checking the Recipient
  Ok
  Organization Id that we expected: 00Dxxxxxx
  Organization Id that we found based on your assertion: 00Dxxxxxx
11. Validating the Signature
  Is the response signed? true
  Is the assertion signed? true
  Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? true
  Ok
12. Checking that the Site URL Attribute contains a valid site url, if provided
  Not Provided
13. Looking for portal and organization id, if provided
  Not Provided
14. Checking if session security level is valid, if provided
  Ok

Subject: 00Dxxxxxxxxx@user@sf.com
Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user

AssertionId: _4c68d3bd54c7dc23c88744fc7adb40f81546421056960

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SSO you can create a permission set and assign them to user which need to access multiple communities and then add that permission set into community group member.

As per docs:

> Grant or remove access for groups of users. Once you add a profile or
>   permission set, all users assigned to that profile or permission set
>   become members of the community.

[Add Members to Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_members.htm&type=5)

Comment: Initially, we proposed this permission set solution but there are some problems by this approach. So we have decided go forward with SSO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of username, i was able to create connection by UserId/any custom field. It worked, was successfully able to login to customer community.